# Why the Allocation of an array with int.MaxValue fails and the allocation of two arrays with the size  int.MaxValue / 2 does not?

Tags: c#

Why the allocation of a byte array with the size `int.MaxValue` fails

```
    byte[] array1 = new byte[int.MaxValue]; // throws an OutOfMemoryException
```

and the allocation of two arrays with the size  `int.MaxValue / 2` does not?

```
    byte[] array2 = new byte[int.MaxValue / 2];
    byte[] array3 = new byte[int.MaxValue / 2];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum size of an object in .NET is 2GB: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx

int.MaxValue + the array overhead is slightly greater than 2 GB.

Comment: (2GB = 2*1024^3) > (2147483647 = MaxValue); allocation fails also for int.MaxValue-50

Comment: That's true. 2GB is exactly 1 more than int.MaxValue

Comment: An array holds some additional information besides its main data storage (some come from `object`, some are specific to arrays), which is why you reach the boundry a little early.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of .NET (4.5 onwards at least) you can allocate objects larger than 2Gb - however you have to set gcAllowVeryLargeObjects - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the value of int.MaxValue in c#, but I think .Net doesn't allow objects larger than 2GB